# .Net Rest API Retrieving the body of the message

Tags: c#, wcf, json, api

I have a Rest API developed using the WCF WinAPI.

```
public class paramval
{
    string name;
}

[ServiceContract]
public class myQuery
{
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "{systemCode}/{objectID}", Method = "POST")]

    public myResult Get(string systemCode, int objectID, paramval pval)
    {
    }

}
```

The value of pval is always null.

I'm using the WCF Web API Test Client tool.

```
URL:      http://localhost:11556/api/contacts/abc/111
Request:  POST
Headers:  Accept:*/*
          Content-Type:application/json
          Content-Length:16
Body      {"name":"Frank"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If I change the type of pval to be JSonString I can receive Json Objects.  I would like something more generic though.

Answer (score 1):

Try annotating your class with the [`DataContractAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) and [`DataMemberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx), and using a public property for `Name` (changed class and property name to use pascal casing):

```
[DataContract]
public class ParamVal 
{ 
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add DataContract and DataMember with the new WCF WebAPI

Answer (score 0):

Your `UriTemplate` only specifies mappings for `systemCode` and `objectID`. Do you need to add to the template to extract a value for the Name property of `paramval` as well?

Comment: The param is not being sent in the URL but in the Body of the POST